# how to change the attributes in a wsdl using jax-ws specific soap webservices

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I was reading about web services , and was creating wsdl from jax-ws source code, i was able to create the wsdl perfectly , i have a many inputs in a request where i need to set minOccurs and maxOccurs for a specific string input in a request, how can i do this via java code. help me in this

my wsdl piece code

```
<xs:element name="person"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="employee" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
  <xs:element name="member" type="xs:string"/> </xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define such limit by jaxb anotations on your classes.
You can have 1, or unbound only as maxoccurency

Comment: then default value is 0 , but how can i change the values to 1 or unbound using annotations here for a string

Comment: how can i change in other forms of soap webservices , like in axis or cxf or RPC

Comment: You change it to one by @XmlElement(required=true) on top of a single value field. It Changes to unbound if the field is a list type. I don't think you can have such control in other frameworks as they used similar annotation but I don't have much experience with them.  You can hower link the full wsdl document to your WS to be served instead of generated one.